# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while using jsoup

Tags: java, eclipse, jsoup

I'm trying to parse an html document in a webservice. According to google, jsoup seem to be the faster and easier html parser, so I included in my project but I get the exception **"Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Message: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"** I have tried everything, but nothings give results. Please help

I add jsoup.jar in my project's libray classpath. 
I am using Eclipse Luna on Windows XP
Java 1.7 apache tomcat 7.0

this is my code:

```
  try {
     url = new URL("http://consulta.muniguate.com/emetra/despliega.php?tplaca="+tplaca+"&nplaca="+nplaca);
     conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
     rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
     while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result += line;
     }
     Document doc = Jsoup.connect(result).get();
     String title= doc.title();
     System.out.println(title);

     rd.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

}

This is the full code:

```
package clases;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


@WebService(serviceName = "Transito")
public class Transito {

@WebMethod(operationName = "consultar_saldo") 
public String consultar_saldo(String tplaca, int nplaca) throws InvocationTargetException {
  String result = "";
  try {
      Document doc= Jsoup.connect("http://www.muniguate.com/utilities/remisiones.htm?tplaca="+tplaca+"&nplaca="+nplaca).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
     String result = doc.title();
     System.out.println(result);
  } catch (Exception e){
     e.getCause();
  }
  return result;

   }
}
```

Comment: There should be a root cause for your InvocationTargetException, look at the "Caused by" of the exception trace it should contains usefull informations.

Comment: @nomoa I am seeing it is caused by a nullpointerexception

Comment: please post the full stack.

Answer (score 0):

`Jsoup.connect()` accepts a url string, not response content

Comment: You should add a link to the API documentation

Answer (score 0):

> "I have tried everything, but nothings give results."

In that case you are doomed since there is nothing left for us to try.

But lets assume that you didn't try everything. Lets assume that [documentation of `Jsoup.connect()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#connect(java.lang.String)) is actually telling the true, and this method is used only to create Connection to resource which should be parsed, not to parse it. Its [`get()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#get()) method job to connect to resource from created Connection, parse it and return it as `Document`.
So this method instead of HTML text of resource, will need information required for connection like URL.

So instead of manually creating `HttpURLConnection` and reading its HTML code, pass string representing URL to `Jsoup.connect()` and then using `get()` connect and parse to this resource.

So instead of

```
URL url = new URL("http://consulta.muniguate.com/emetra/despliega.php?tplaca="+tplaca+"&nplaca="+nplaca);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        conn.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
String result = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result += line;
}
```

Simply use

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://consulta.muniguate.com/emetra/despliega.php?tplaca="+tplaca+"&nplaca="+nplaca).get();
```

Now you should be able to use

```
String title = doc.title();
System.out.println(title);
```

Comment: I already tried with this:
`Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.muniguate.com/utilities/remisiones.htm")
           .data("tplaca", "P")
           .data("nplaca", "123")
           .userAgent("Mozilla")
           .post();´`
Still nothing

Comment: @montjoile What do you mean by "*Still nothing*"? Do you get any errors/exceptions/incorrect results?

Comment: same exception "Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Message: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

Comment: @montjoile Post simple and short but compilable code example which will let us reproduce this problem. Also post complete stacktrace. Without it I am not sure if anyone here will be able to help you.

Comment: I posted the entire code Im using, but the getCause of the exception is saying that the cause is a nullpointerexception. I am totally lost

Comment: Your posted code example will not even compile (you have two `doc` variables). Take your time while creating [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and be sure that it will let us reproduce your actual problem (there is even a chance that you will find cause of your problem while trying to reproduce it from the scratch so it is definitely worth spending fair amount of time on it).

Comment: upps, I was testing. now it is as I am working on it